# Radio Button doesn't display correctly , android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-radiobutton

I'm new in android programming , when i want to add a group of radio button doesn't display correctly the text and the radio button are mixed you can see the picture to understand what i mean:

[image]

and this my simple code I hope you can help me , thank you so much

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gRadio">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/rB1" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/rB2" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/rB3" />
    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

---

- Android Studio 2.1.2
- jdk1.8.0_31
- Gradle  2.10
- android plugin 2.1.2
- compile SDK version API 23
- Build Tools version  24

Comment: The layout should work, have you test on a physic device ?

Comment: what is your root layout ? post full XML code

Comment: @L.Swifter  no I didn't tested on a pgysic device but it should display correctly in android studio

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson I will edit the post to add the full XML code

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Try restarting android studio.

Comment: Post your full XML..not only `RadioButton` part

Comment: have you checked the screen size you are working on ??

Comment: @priyankvex I restarted android studio and also update it to 2.1.3 and update also gradle nothing works, I  find the solution i made a mistake I render layout in android studio with the vesion sdk 8 and my API compile SDK 23

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson unfortunately i have just those three buttons

Comment: Thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now. i made a mistake, I render my layout in IDE with ***sdk version 8*** although my ***compile SDK version API 23*** , Thank you all .

Answer (score 0):

**So for such a scenario, there is a cure.**

**1.** Try to use AppCompatRadioButton 
Set a custom style to it which extends from ***@android:style/Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.RadioButton***
with following attributes

***"buttonTint"*** and value **@color/red**

***"android:button"*** and value **@drawable/custom_radio_selector**

**2.** Add two image drawables, one for checked and other for unchecked state.

**3.** Create a custom drawable selector "custom_radio_selector.xml"

```
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_on" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_off" />

<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_on" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_off" />

<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_off" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_on" />
```

where **ic_radio_off.png** and **ic_radio_on.png** are the image drawbles added as required.